# Starting from any a,ß-unsaturated carbonyl compound, how would you prepare the following Organic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Is this correct so far? Is there any other way to do this? Was it wrong of me to add KCN instead of HCN? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!
[image]

Comment: This is basically correct. Addition of alkali metal cyanides favours 1,4 addition. Phenyl Grignard should add to the ketone rather than the nitrile. You'll need to be careful with the workup to avoid elimination of the tertiary OH, I would suggest using aq. NH4Cl rather than acid.

Comment: Your choice for KCN is good because it commercially available in kilogram scale as a salt. As this salt, the cyanide already is free, contrasting to its undissociated state in the weak acid HCN is. Be careful though when using it because some chemists are unable recognize the scent of HCN.